# Is it exist a sequence of move notation of Rubik's Cube so that it show up all possible permutations?

Tags: group-theory, rubiks-cube

Recently, I've success to prove that given a Rubik's Cube which has been solved, any sequences of moves will lead it to the original position if repeat long enough. But now I'm wonder that:

*Is there any sequences of moves that lead the Rubik's Cube to show up all of its possible permutations before go back to the original position?*

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube), there are exactly $43,252,003,274,489,856,000$ possible permutations that can be reached solely by turning the sides of the cube. Such a sequences of moves must pass exactly $43,252,003,274,489,856,000$ permutations and go back to the original position right after.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/184760/81360). The answer is yes, supposedly.