# How many steps before reaching an already-seen permutation of Rubik's cube?

Tags: permutations, rubiks-cube

Given a 3x3 Rubik's cube with an initial state, how many maximum moves will it take before a state is repeated (The number of moves after which, we can no longer make a move which generates a new state)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have improved the question. I am asking "If you are given a Rubik's cube, how many moves can you make on that cube after which it is guaranteed that the move you make will get you to state that you have already visited before."

Comment: Are you asking for the [Devil's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184760/brute-force-method-of-solving-the-cube-how-many-moves-would-it-take)? This is a move sequence that visits every single cube position exactly once. It's length is N-1 moves, where N is the number of possible cube positions.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis yes, Thanks!

Comment: answer at: https://bruce.cubing.net/index.html, so after 43,252,003,274,489,856,000 moves we can't make any such moves that produces new state